# Solr 6 not available on mydomain.com:8983, but ip:8983

Tags: solr, centos7

when I use IP:8983,it work.
But if I use mydomain.com:8983,it did not work.
Please help how to fix this.
I am using Solr 6 on Centos 7.
So I have to modify the httpd.conf or modify any solr files?

Comment: the problem is that your DNS is not resolving to your IP. do you own `mydomain.com`? if so, then check the DNS settings with the registrar to make sure that the IP is correct. alternatively, you could make an entry in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: thanks, I do have mydomain.com and I can visit mydomain.com site normally！You mean that I have to add “IP:mydomain.com” to /etc/hosts? I used CDN for my site, dose it effect sth.?

Comment: so when you browse to `mydomain.com` on the regular port (80), it shows you a web page that's hosted on the same CentOS server?

Comment: yes, it's the website I put on the Centos Server.

Comment: anything wrong for my httpd config? <VirtualHost IP:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/site>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>